# Sequence of elements having a convergent subsequence -NBHM $2014$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, compactness

Question is to find which of the following are true?

1. Let $V$ be the space of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with compact support endowed with metric $$d(f,g)=\bigg(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(t)-g(t)|^2\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which vanish outside $[0,1]$. define $f_n(x)=f(x-n)$ for $x\in \mathbb{N}$. Then $(f_n)$ has a convergent sub sequence in $V$.
2. Let $\varphi, \psi$ be continuous function on $[0,1]$. Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ with its sup norm topology suchthat, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ the functions $f_n$ are continuously diffrerentiable and for all $x\in[0,1]$ and for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $|f_n(x)|\leq \varphi(x)$ and $|f_n'(x)|\leq \psi(x)$ Then there exists a sub sequence of $(f_n)$ which converges in $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$.
3. Let $\{A_n\}$ be a sequence of orthogonal matrices in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. then it has a convergent subsequence.

I am sure that $3$ is true as Orthogonal matrices are compact and every sequence in compact space has a convergent subsequence.

I see that $2$ is also correct by Arzela Ascoli Theorem.

I am not so sure about $1$ and actually i did not understand the idea behind that.

Please help me to see this question more clearly and help me to answer this.

Thank you.

Comment: Continuous function with compact support are dense in $C[0,1]$

Comment: @Tojamaru So.. how does that help me in this case?

Comment: For (1): if exists the convergent subsequence, the limit is...

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla : I am sorry, i could not get your point...

Comment: What's the meaning of "with compact support endowed"?

Comment: "[functions] with compact support, [space] endowed"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any supposed limit $g$ (continuous function with compact support), take $n_0$ large enough s.t. for $n\ge n_0$: ${\rm supp}\,f_n\cap{\rm supp}\,g=\emptyset$. Now, if $n_k\ge n_0$:
$$
d(f_{n_k},g)^2=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f_{n_k}(t)-g(t)|^2dt=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f_{n_k}(t)|^2dt+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|g(t)|^2dt\ge
$$

$$
\ge\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f_{n_k}(t)|^2dt
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(t)|^2dt,
$$
and this implies $f=0$. The property is only true in this trivial case.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not get your point.... why would ${\rm supp}\,f_n\cap{\rm supp}\,g=\emptyset$ and why would last equality hold :O

Comment: Draw some $f$. Draw $f_n$ (it will be a translated of $f$) for several $n$.

Comment: Excuse me for my dumbness but i am unable to think of a continuous  function which vanish outside $[0,1]$.. I can think of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ but they are not zero outside $[0,1]$.. No obvious example is coming to my mind...

Comment: A function isn't a **formula**. *Draw* a function with compact support in [0,1].

Comment: +1 for reminding me that a function is not a formula :) I would try to work it out :) Thank you :)

Comment: Bad copy/paste, see the correction. The last equality is true because $f_n$ is a translated of $f$.

Comment: Now it makes some sense to me... you have not written $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_n(t)g(t)$ just because ${\rm supp}\,f_n\cap{\rm supp}\,g=\emptyset$.. Am i correct? I could not understand ${\rm supp}\,f_n\cap{\rm supp}\,g=\emptyset$ though.... I have plotted graph of a function which vanish on $[0,1]$... $f_1(x)$ would be shifted to right by $1$ unit, $f_2(x)$ would be shifted to right by one more unit and so on... so, supposrt of $f_n$ would be $[n,n+1]$ so, ${\rm supp}\,f_n\cap{\rm supp}\,g=\emptyset$ Is this the reason?

Comment: Right. When supports are disjoint, $(f+g)^2=f^2+g^2$ because $fg$ vanish.

Comment: Oh yes.... But I was expecting that i should use Arzela Ascoli for this :O and one more doubt is that I guess we are assuming it is a convergent sequence but not a sub sequence... I am confused ..

Comment: The reasoning works with subsequences.

Comment: I do not know :O I would think for some more time... Thanks for your interest... :)

Comment: I would now conlcude (you have almost done it) as : Suppose $f_{n_k}\rightarrow g$ then $d(f_{n_k},g)<\epsilon$ for large $n_k$ and in our case this tells that $\epsilon >d(f_{n_k},g)^2\geq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(t)|^2dt,$ i.e., $f\equiv 0$ which is not the case always... so there does not exists a convergent sub sequence.... Thank you again for your help.... :)